# Charging animation not shown after flashing original ROM

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

I've been playing a lot with my Samsung SM-T210 lately (Galaxy Tab 3 7" Wifi) replacing its stock recovery with TWRP, rooting it using SuperSU 2.37 and changing some files of the system partition.

Later, I tried modifying the `/system/bin/playlpm` file (called just lpm in other devices) to make the device boot just as soon as power is supplied. After trying many times I realized that it wasn't working so I went back to flash the stock ROM of the device.

Finally, I did a factory reset using the recovery flashed with Samsung stock ROM. After connecting the charger, I found out that the `/system/bin/playlpm` file was not been executed at all, since no animation was being played when the charger was plugged, only the initial image of the battery with a static image on top of it.

The animation should be something like this:

[image: animation]

The initial image seen is something like this:

[image: initial image]

After flashing the Samsung stock ROM the device should be as good as new and the standard stock animation should be played when connected to the charger.

Anyone knows why this is happening and how to solve the issue?

Comment: @firelord could you tell me why did you erase the other tags?

Comment: The reasoning behind tags is not that something is mentioned hence the  tag of that word should be used but *tags should define what the question is about*. None of the previous tags were defining your question. I used the device tag because the question is device specific. I didn't see other relevant tags though. I was unsure on using stock rom tag.

Comment: @Firelord I beg to defer because even though this issue appeared on this device it has something to do with Android OS which have to do with all Android devices. In my humble opinion, the fact that the LPM -PlayLPM in Samsung- service is not starting has to do with the OS and is not device specific.

Comment: The usage of device specific tag doesn't mean that it something has only to do with hardware but to software as well. You can always [edit]  and add tags but it is always better to have strong justification for their usage.